# how do you test an if statement in javascript/angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

here is some code i have got:

```
$scope.changePassword = function () {
                sessionService.save($scope.sessionData);
                if(sessionService.account.newPassword ==  sessionService.account.currentPassword) {
                     return false;
                }
                webServiceDal.changePassword().success(function (response) {
                    if (response.ChangePasswordAppResponse.errorFlag)
                        $scope.globalError = response.ChangePasswordAppResponse.returnMsg;
                    else
                        $location.path('/my-preferences');
                });
            };
```

how would you write a unit test for this? do i need to mock something.
im new to javascript/angular js unit testing and so need some guidance as to where to start.
i have looked at the docs but they dont have examples for if else statements

Comment: You would need to mock sessionService so that you can control what it contains to impact the if statement.

Comment: @KevinB this posted through well late. but yes you are correct. should have put it as answer so i could accept it. what is the advantage of writing a comment answer rather than an answer answer? but thanks anyway!

Comment: @RagingBull, answers are usually expected to contain more elaborate info, links to docs, an example, etc.

Comment: Right, it was more of a suggestion, that someone with more time/expertise can expand on. Feel free to use it to come up with a solution and provide as an answer. Kinda difficult to come up with a relevant answer not knowing what testing frameworks you are using.

Comment: @KevinB yes i have already achieved a solution for some reason this question was delayed and only posted 15 minutes ago when should have been posted this morning

Comment: @JimL thanks for the insight. comments to the answers rep no favours though! (not that im jel)

Comment: @RagingBull true, but they are just points :) I often add comments as I usually don't have time to write down long/good answers. A helpful hint in a comment can be very helpful though when you're stuck with something :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock your objects before your unit tests, and the methods/properties that you use of your objects.

So you need to mock:

```
sessionService
```

and its methods/properties:

```
save(), account.newPassword, account.currentPassword
```

And

```
webServiceDal
```

and its method:

```
changePassword
```

Then you need to inject the angular injections that you use:

```
$scope, $location
```

And remember to inject angular parameters using the `_AngularName_` syntax.